# Find $\theta$ for which $\sin m \theta = \cos n \theta$

Tags: trigonometry

> **Question:** Find $\theta$ for which $\sin m \theta = \cos n \theta$

---

My attempt:

$$\cos(m\theta)=\sin(\pi/2 - m\theta)$$
$$=\sin\big[k\pi + (-1)^k (\pi/2-m\theta)\big]$$
Since $\cos(m \theta)=\sin(n \theta)$, therefore:
$$\big[k\pi + (-1)^k (\pi/2-m\theta)\big]=n\theta$$
And hence we get $$\theta = \frac{\pi\Big[k+\frac{(-1)^k}{2}\Big]}{n+(-1)^km}$$

$m,n,k$ can be any number $\in \mathbb{R}$ as in my case.

But is there any better representation of $\theta$ instead of what I've shown? I know I'm not wrong anywhere, but still if there's a shorter representation of the value of $\theta$ in terms some real number (positive, negative or zero), do write an answer.

Regards,
Mathbg

Comment: It appears that $m$ and $n$ are 'given' in the problem, so that the only variable is actually $k$.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri Yeah, it's true. But still if there's a different answer, do tell. I mean, better way of representation

Answer (score 3):

I think your solution's good. It doesn't get much 'simpler' I believe. Perhaps the presentation could be made better. We have that

$$\sin(y)=x\iff y={(-1)}^k\arcsin(x)+k\pi$$

for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. Hence, from $\cos(n\theta)=\sin(\pi/2-n\theta)$ we have that

\begin{align}
\sin(m\theta)=\cos(n\theta)&\iff m\theta={(-1)}^k(\pi/2-n\theta)+k\pi\\
&\iff(m+{(-1)}^kn)\theta=\left(k+\frac{{(-1)}^k}{2}\right)\pi\\
&\iff\theta=\left(\frac{2k+{(-1)}^k}{m+{(-1)}^kn}\right)\frac{\pi}{2}
\end{align}

Comment: Yeah good, though same as mine except you took the $\frac{\pi}{2}$ out of the block. (+1)

Answer (score 2):

HINT: use that $$\sin(m\theta)-\cos(n\theta)=-2 \sin \left(-\frac{\theta  m}{2}-\frac{\theta  n}{2}+\frac{\pi }{4}\right) \sin
   \left(-\frac{\theta  m}{2}+\frac{\theta  n}{2}+\frac{\pi }{4}\right)$$

Comment: So basically, $\sin
   \left(-\frac{\theta  m}{2}+\frac{\theta  n}{2}+\frac{\pi }{4}\right)=0$ and taking its general form of representation, we can do. Good idea, but still, it would be a big thing. Thanks for the idea (+1)

Comment: See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html

Comment: $\sin\left(-\frac{\theta m}{2}+\frac{\theta n}{2}+\frac{\pi }{4}\right)=0$ gives you "half" of the solutions, $\sin\left(-\frac{\theta m}{2}-\frac{\theta n}{2}+\frac{\pi }{4}\right)=0$ gives you the others. Therefore either $-\frac{\theta m}{2}+\frac{\theta n}{2}+\frac{\pi }{4} = 2k$ or $-\frac{\theta m}{2}-\frac{\theta n}{2}+\frac{\pi }{4}= 2k,$ for some integer $k.$ I get the same result.

Answer (score 2):

In the approach shown in the question, you convert the cosine to a sine.
Suppose instead you convert the sine t a cosine:

$$ \sin(m\theta) = \cos\left(\frac\pi2 - m\theta \right).$$

Therefore we have to solve for $\theta$ in
$$ \cos\left(\frac\pi2 - m\theta \right) = \cos(n\theta).$$

But we also know $\cos(-n\theta) = \cos(n\theta).$
An angle $\theta$ is part of the solution if and only if it
solves one of the following two equations:
$$
\frac\pi2 - m\theta= n\theta + 2k\pi \quad\text{or}\quad
\frac\pi2 - m\theta= -n\theta + 2k\pi,
$$
where $k$ is an integer.

That is,
$$ \frac\pi2 - m\theta= \pm n\theta + 2k\pi, $$
$$ m\theta \pm n\theta =  \frac\pi2 -  2k\pi, $$
$$ \theta  =  \frac{\frac\pi2 -  2k\pi}{m \pm n}
 = \left(\frac{1 - 4k}{m \pm n}\right) \frac \pi2. $$

Since $k$ is an arbitrary integer (positive or negative), you can equally well write
$$ \theta = \left(\frac{1 + 4k}{m \pm n}\right) \frac \pi2. $$

---

Checking this against the result in the question, the $m+n$ case
produces the same set of values of $\theta$ as you get for even values of $k$ in the question, and the $m-n$ case produces the same set of values of $\theta$ as you get for odd values of $k.$

Comment: Yeah, I'd done this way as well, still, thanks a lot for your effort. (+1)